# Solving non linear ODE for y , x and y'

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a Math lecture , we solved the following DE 
 $$yy'^2+2xy'-y=0$$ 
in 3 ways :
First we solved for y' by taking y' in one side , making a substitution and integrating.

We solved the DE again for x and one more time for y as following :

We solved the DE for y , by taking y in one side and called y' as p , then we differentiated both sides w.r.t x to get finally a separable DE in p and x that can be solved easily.

And we solved the DE for x by taking x in one side and called y' as p , then we differentiated both side w.r.t y to get finally a separable DE in p and y that can be solved easily.

My problem is that I do not understand why can we need to solve a DE for x and y ?? solving the DE for y' gave us the solution we need . What do the solutions gotten from solving for x and y represent ?? and why do we differentiate w.r.t x when solving for y and differentiate w.r.t. y when solving for x ? ..Is this a standard method to solve non linear DE?? If you can provide me a reference name that introduces this method of solution ,I will be grateful!

Comment: Set $z=y^2$ to find that the equation is a Clairaut equation $z=z'x+\frac14(z')^2$.